# How I can update 2 of my rows randomly, that have this codition F01=1 And F03=1 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I update 2 of my rows randomly from 4 other rows that have this condition `F01=1 And F02=1` in a table with 5 rows?
and i want the number of that rows that changed after the execute of the code.

like this

```
ID   F01   F02         ID    F01    F02
1    0     1           1     0      1
2    1     1           2     A      1
3    1     1      -->  3     1      1
4    1     1           4     1      1
5    1     1           5     A      1
```

And finally i have the number 2 and 5 in another table.

The numbers are just for example.

I can't use newid() because SQL says you can not use order by in subqueries.

This is my code that doesn't work

```
Update Chess.dbo.Sheet1$ 
set F01 = A 
Where ID in (select top 2 ID 
             from Chess.dbo.Sheet1$ 
             where (select ID from Chess.dbo.Sheet1$ order by NEWID())
```

Comment: Show us your query, the one that doesn't work, and perhaps it will be easier to understand what to do.

Comment: Wrong way round, you can't use a subquery, because you want to order by newid() ....

Comment: @jarlh take a look again. i plus my code that dosent work.

Comment: @FarshadShahsavari you have changed your question so much that the answers provided for your original question looks a bit irrelevant. You should only add more stuff to expand on your original question if required. Otherwise you should ask a new question.

Comment: @jarlh yes you are right.

Comment: @Farshad Shahsavari  Try to use "row_number over partition" function . I think it will work for you. Let me know if you need any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
 SELECT TOP 30 *
 FROM TableName 
 WHERE F01 = 1 AND F02 = 1
 ORDER BY NEWID()
)
UPDATE CTE 
 SET ColumnName = 'NewValue'
```

OR

```
UPDATE t
 SET t.ColumnName = 'NewValue'
FROM (
     SELECT TOP 30 *
     FROM TableName 
     WHERE F01 = 1 AND F02 = 1
     ORDER BY NEWID()
    )t
```

### Edit

If you want the updated row IDs once the randomly selected rows has been updated.

you can do the following

```
 DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT);

;WITH CTE AS 
(
 SELECT TOP 30 *
 FROM TableName 
 WHERE F01 = 1 AND F02 = 1
 ORDER BY NEWID()
)
UPDATE CTE 
 SET ColumnName = 'NewValue'
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @Table(ID)

-- now select from the table variable 
SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Comment: ORDER BY in common table expression?

Comment: @mcl - Yes that is valid in conjunction with `TOP`. It controls the rows selected by TOP not the display order.

Comment: mcl's answer is better in this case, since the OP said he wants to return the ids of the rows that where updated. As far as I know, it's impossible with a CTE or a derived table.

Comment: @zohar perfectly possible with the output clause.

Comment: @ZoharPeled the question has been edited, the original post did not have this requirement.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks, I'ts always good to learn new things.
M.Ali: I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @ids AS TABLE(id INT)
INSERT INTO @ids(id) SELECT TOP(2) ID FROM Chess.dbo.Sheet1$ WHERE F01 = 1 AND F02 = 1 ORDER BY NEWID()
UPDATE Chess.dbo.Sheet1$ SET F01 = 'A'
WHERE ID IN (
SELECT id
FROM @ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script but it updates them one by one. so you should execute the script twice to update two rows.

```
   Update T
        Set F01 = 'A'
    Output Deleted.ID
    From Test T
    Where ID IN (Select ROUND(((Max(ID) - Min(ID) -1) * RAND() + Min(ID)), 0) 
                From Test 
                Where F01 = '1' And F02 = '1')
```